# Causality - Why do we typically have an exogenous noise term for every variable in SCMs?

Tags: machine-learning, causality

I am working on Deep Learning so I will try to ask this question from that perspective. It seems that most recent works in CausalML uses the framework of SCMs, and that assumes each observed variable has one corresponding exogenous noise variable.

Now my question is: **Why do we always need exogenous noise? For example, what could go wrong with the following SCM?**
$$
\begin{aligned}
X&= f_X(N_x)\\
Y&= f_Y(N_y)\\
Z&= f_Z(Y,N_z)\\
M&=f_M(X,Y,Z)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $N_i$ means noise. So in this example, $M$ has no variation from exogenous noise, but it is still "caused" by $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: "*I am working on Deep Learning so I will try to ask this question from that perspective.*" You didn't mention deep learning after that sentence so it is unclear to me what your question has to do with being from a "deep learning perspective". Can you clarify or elaborate in your question by editing it?

Comment: "*I am working on Deep Learning so I will try to ask this question from that perspective.*"

I can only guess at what that means.

Comment: My *guess* is that you are using deep learning models where you have not modelled any noise or measurement error on the inputs. That doesn't actually mean there isn't noise. There could be (and often is) noise that just isn't being accounted except by trying to "average it out" over training examples. Indeed, such deep learning models are aiming to learn the conditional expectation.

Comment: [Gelman *et al* 2023](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/causal_quartets.pdf) is a fun "causal quartets" paper discussing how we should be more thoughtful about using just averages for causal inference.

Comment: "*Why do we always need exogenous noise?*" We don't always need exogenous noise. It is just very common for exogenous noise to matter. This is because we're not measuring and controlling everything.

Comment: "*So in this example,  has no variation from exogenous noise, but it is still "caused" by ,,.*"  There is nothing mathematically wrong with this, and in some applications I have encountered situations like this.

Comment: It would be a weird flex, but even an example where all the variables are [constant random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution#Constant_random_variable) would technically be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! When I say "I am working on DL", I mainly mean that I have not systematically learned different causality frameworks and how they are developed. For example, I know about Rubin's and Pearl's framework are essentially the same in many aspects but I cannot clearly say how they are same or different. And I am referring to SCMs which is commonly used in Causal+ML/DL papers.

Comment: Could you please give me some references where people use/assume the existence of deterministic functions in SCMs either in papers or textbooks?

Comment: Offhand I don't know of a published example. Discrete event simulations and other process model often have such deterministic functions and you *can* develop a SCM for them, but I have yet to see a published example where they additionally drew an SCM for their process model. Mathematically such examples are easy to construct. Are you just looking for an example, or are you looking for something further?

Comment: I am trying to find examples where people actually use deterministic function in the causal literature, which could be potentially used as a reference.

Answer (score 5):

## It's a common assumption with some justification and a lot of benefits

Having a noise term for each variable is a frequently made assumption which can be argued to be sufficiently realistic to be justifiable, and which offers great advantages for the identifiability of causal structure.

### Justification

These are the common justifications I'm aware of:

1. **Avoiding determinism**. The noise term avoids deterministic relationships. The idea is that nature isn't completely deterministic, and certainly not given the often coarse and incomplete nature of our measurements.
2. **Weak random interactions with other variables**. Many causal structures assume things like "no unobserved confounders", and are assumed to be something of a closed system. Clearly, that is not the case for most sets of variables, so one way to acknowledge interactions with out-of-system variables is through (typically weak) random interactions which can be represented by random noise.

## Advantages

1. **Identifiability**. The noise terms do a lot of the heavy lifting for the identifiability of the underlying DAG in causal structure learning. Typical model classes are, for example, additive/multiplicative noise models with linear or non-linear functions. For an introduction to the general idea, see [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3757.pdf).
2. **Rich canonical model class.** When there is an exogenous noise term for each variable, it is easy to model different degrees of stochasticity for different variables by choosing the parameters of the noise distribution. In this way, the model with exogenous noise in fact contains the one without - one can simply set the means and variances of the noise terms to zero. Additionally, intercept terms can be included in the mean of the noise, making for an altogether flexible model class that can be written in a canonical form.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation! Do you know any reference like a paper or textbook where the necessity or benefits of exogenous is more systematically and comprehensively discussed? 

Or instead of starting with assumptions on the existence of exogenous noise, they did an investigation on what if there is no exogenous noise.

Comment: I'd recommend the [Elements of Causal Inference](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/056a11be-ce3a-44b9-8987-a6c68fce8d9b/11283.pdf). For example, page 21 (point 3, paragraph 2) describes the same idea as the second justification in my answer. Sections 2 and 3 have a lot more details on the reasoning behind the SCM class, so they may be interesting to you.

Comment: @Scriddie Thank you for sharing that reference!